# Why does a test merge show conflicts that don't occur in actual merge?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When performing a merge in Subversion there is an option to Test the merge. I have often seen this test uncover conflicts, but then when the actual merge is performed those conflicts do not occur. Does anyone know why this sometimes happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this happens when there are multiple distinct ranges. Subversion will test merge the first range and see no conflicts. It then test merges the second range checking against your current working copy. Because the first range has not been applied the working copy is not in a good state to merge the second: you get a conflict. When actually merging the first range does get applied to the working copy. The second range is then able to merge without issue.

Comment: That does make sense but in that case I don't understand the point of the test merge. Maybe it is just best not to use it over multiple ranges?

Comment: Test merge is still useful for a single range. Or if you want to apply one range at a time. Unfortunately I don't know a good way to test multiple ranges at once. I don't even bother with test merges and just keep an extra working copy around for merging purposes.

Comment: That makes sense. And yes I don't personally bother with test merges, a coworker just noticed this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but is it coming up with "Errors" or just warnings?  And is there an example you can direct us to or show?  The Test Merge may have other coding in it to analyze the merge that under normal merge you would not add.

Comment: It's just showing that there are conflicts, which is OK. But then when I perform the actual merge there are zero conflicts.